# Remove the fixed-size constraint in numpy fixed-size array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have now a fixed-size string numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

str_arr = np.array(['test1', 'test2'], dtype='<U5')
str_arr[0] = 'longer_string'
print(str_arr)
```

And it returns

```
['longe' 'test2']
```

I'd like to remove this limit. Would there be a way to do so? Below is an example of my failed attempt:

```
str_arr_copy = str_arr.astype(str)
str_arr_copy[0] = 'longer_string'
print(str_arr_copy)
```

And it doesn't help at all.

Thank you!

Comment: `str_arr.astype('U100')` gives you more space, but doesn't eliminate the limit.  For this work a regular list is probably better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to `dtype=object`, do the assignment, and then convert back to `dtype=str`:

```
>>> str_arr_copy = str_arr.astype(object)
>>> str_arr_copy[0] = 'longer_string'
>>> print(str_arr_copy.astype(str))
array(['longer_string', 'test2'], 
      dtype='<U13')
```

Comment: Using `arr.tolist()` to generate the intermediate copy runs in about the same time.